# Any way to determine wireless connection or cable connection via PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wireless

On the website, I want to know if the visitor is using wireless or cable connection. Any way to do that?

The reason I want to do this is to offer geo location service when the user is using wireless which is more accurate than using cable. I don't want to offer this service at all when it's a cable connection because the location would be wrong.

Comment: That would be pretty much impossible. Forget about it.

Comment: If it's incredibly important, you could write a Java applet that I'm sure could determine that. Then you can call a Javascript method from the applet and pass it a value telling it what it is. Then your Javascript can go from there. Of course, then your assuming an applet can be run

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#accuracy

Comment: Why don't you just display that as a warning?

Comment: `wireless which is more accurate than using cable` wait, what?

Comment: What make you think that geo location of cable connection would be wrong?

Comment: ^ I think he means `mobile which is much more accurate than a home or work connection`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form action="conType.php">
I am visiting via  ...<br />
<input type="radio" name="conType" value="wireless" /> Wireless<br />
<input type="radio" name="conType" value="cable" /> Cable
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What if Im in a wireless connection and I chose a cable connection. Would that makes difference?

Comment: Wow gee I wonder which 2 accounts downvoted me? Ravinder Singh and Ravinder Singh? Went from 990 to 989 and from 531 to 530. Grow up.

Comment: They got merged and suspended, you win. ;) (If you're curious how I got here, there is little fuss in [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164706/author-is-changed-for-the-same-answer))

Comment: Wow ThiefMaster rocks :) Thanks for the link Shadow!

Answer (score 1):

No, this should not be possible. For details on Browser and JavaScript security look here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security